# Change event code for two inter related text boxes

Tags: excel, vba

I use an  UserForm with 3 Text boxes.
TestBox1 for entering numeric values(LP).
TextBox2 for entring  Discount in percentage  and TextBox3 is for displaying the discounted value.
Now I want to get the Discount in percent if the user puts the discounted value in TextBox3.
l have tried  Change event but both the Textbox values are changing.

```
Option Explicit

Dim Lp As Double
Dim Perc As Double

Private Sub Calculate()
Lp = CDbl(TextBox1.Value)
Perc = CDbl(TextBox2.Value)
TextBox3.Value = Lp - Lp * Perc / 100
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

TextBox2.Value = Lp - Lp * CDbl(TextBox1.Value) / 100
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
TextBox2.Value = (Lp - TextBox2.Value) * 100 / Lp
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call Calculate
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show us what you have already tried doing (even though it doesn't produce your expected results) - It's much easier to debug code when you can see it!

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Which errors do you get? You need to be much more precise. Help us to help you. Note that it does not make an sense to change the value `TextBox2.Value` in the `TextBox2_Change` because this will cause an endless trigger of that change event. Actually I highly recommend to rename your TextBoxes to something meaningful so you don't mix them up all the time. Using numbers in names is a very bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a procedure for calculation and run it in both change events of your textboxes.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    CalculateResult
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    CalculateResult
End Sub

Private Sub CalculateResult()
    If TextBox1.Value <> vbNullString And TextBox2.Value <> vbNullString Then
        Textbox3.Value = TextBox1.Value * TextBox2.Value 'adjust your calculation
    Else
        Textbox3.Value = "fill box 1 and 2 first"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There ae two different calculation for each text box 2 and 3.         TextBox2.value= textbox1.value - textbox1.value/100          and               TextBox3.value = (textbox1.value - textbox1.value)*100/textbox1.value.

Comment: @TBanerjee The second calculation doesn't make sense `(textbox1.value - textbox1.value)` is `0` and followed by `*` and `/` the result will always be `0`. Also I don't get where your issue is just put both of these lines into `TextBox1_Change` event.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the error, It would be (textbox1.value - textbox2.value)

Comment: Option Explicit

Dim Lp As Double
Dim Perc As Double

Private Sub Calculate()
Lp = CDbl(TextBox1.Value)
Perc = CDbl(TextBox2.Value)
TextBox3.Value = Lp - Lp * Perc / 100
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

TextBox3.Value = Lp - Lp * CDbl(TextBox1.Value) / 100
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
TextBox2.Value = (Lp - TextBox2.Value) * 100 / Lp
End Sub

I have tried the code but it is not working:-    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call Calculate
End Sub

Comment: @TBanerjee Please don't put code in comments. Instead edit your original question and add your code there. In VBA line breaks matter and we cannot see them in comments. Also tell what is wrong with that code or ask something. Just posting code without text is pretty useless for us to help you.